# Move x-axis below zero line in e-charts for R

Tags: r, echarts

I have made an interactive plot with e-charts for r. The y-axis has negative values causing a horizontal x-axis to be drawn at zero. How can I move this line to the bottom (at the value of -100)? And, second how can I show all date values (preferably days) on the x-axis (as shown in the ggplot example below)

[image]

```
####################
# interactive plot #
####################

library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(echarts4r)

birthdate <-  ymd("1980-04-20")

timeline <- seq(ymd(Sys.Date()-14), (ymd(Sys.Date()+14)), by = "days")

t <- as.numeric(timeline - birthdate)

physical <-  sin(2*pi*t/23)*100

emotional <-  sin(2*pi*t/28)*100

intellectual <-  sin(2*pi*t/33)*100

df <- tibble(timeline,t, physical, emotional, intellectual)  

df <- df |> pivot_longer(cols = c('physical', 'emotional', 'intellectual'),
                         names_to = 'biorhythms',
                         values_to = 'value')

df$biorhythms <- as.factor(df$biorhythms)

# view data tibble
df

# interactive plot
df |> dplyr::group_by(biorhythms) %>% 
  e_charts(x = timeline) |> 
  e_line(value) |>
  e_format_y_axis(suffix = "%") |>
  e_mark_line(data = list(xAxis = Sys.Date()), title = "Today", symbol = 'none') |>
  e_title("Biorhythm Pseudo-Science") |>
  e_tooltip() |> 
  e_theme("dark-digerati")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your first question, just add `e_x_axis(axisLine = list(onZero = FALSE)) |>` to your code:

```
# interactive plot
df |> dplyr::group_by(biorhythms) %>% 
  e_charts(x = timeline) |> 
  e_line(value) |>
  e_x_axis(axisLine = list(onZero = FALSE)) |>
  e_format_y_axis(suffix = "%") |>
  e_mark_line(data = list(xAxis = Sys.Date()), title = "Today", symbol = 'none') |>
  e_title("Biorhythm Pseudo-Science") |>
  e_tooltip() |> 
  e_theme("dark-digerati")
```

Regarding your second question, aren't those numbers actually days? I think it is better to add a new issue for that one and try to show/explain what you want as an output. Thanks!

Comment: First, thx for your answer! This works! Concerning the second question, those are indeed dates which echarts automatically converts to this standard. However, it would be nice if the original format would be retained on the x-axis i.e., 26-11-2022 (for all the dates in the timeline object). In ggplot this is no problem but I don't know how to get this done in echarts

Comment: @Kensho What if you change the dates into character values, and after that turn them into factors?

Comment: This works to some extend (I can change them directly from dates to factor, the in between step via character values is not necessary, using df$timeline <- as.factor(df$timeline)) and then it shows some dates. However,  I hoped to get all the days and find a way to turn these labels 90 degrees for readability. In ggplot I can do that with scale_x_date(breaks = 'days') and  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))

Comment: Ah yes, you are right about that extra step. For the rotation you can add `axisLabel = list(rotate = 90)` to the arguments of `e_x_axis()` function. I am pretty sure there are possibilities you can let the chart show smaller steps in te dates. Maybe you can find something in the official echarts documentation? Good luck!

Comment: That is it! With the rotation it shows all the dates just as in the ggplot example. Awesome! Thank you soo much.

Comment: Happy to be of any help @Kensho! `echarts4r` keeps on amazing me, everything always seems to be possible.

Comment: If you're that enthusiastic, you could perhaps look at another echarts4r question I have posted :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73033434/how-to-plot-a-horizontal-line-departing-from-the-second-y-axis-in-echarts4r-for